# Didn't display empty MySQL query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a function :

```
function getNgoIn_the_field_Jobs($ngo_id){
global $db;
return $db->query('SELECT `in_the_field_jobs`.*, `ngo`.`title` AS `ngo_title`, `ngo`.`money` AS `ngo_money`, `ngo`.`time` AS `ngo_time`, `ngo`.`love` AS `ngo_love`, `ngo`.`rating` AS `ngo_rating`, `ngo`.`logo` AS `ngo_logo` 
                    FROM `in_the_field_jobs` 
                    INNER JOIN `ngo` 
                    ON (`ngo`.`ngo_id` = `in_the_field_jobs`.`ngo_id`)
                    WHERE `in_the_field_jobs`.`ngo_id` = ' . (int)$ngo_id );
}
```

And my query is :

```
<?php $in_the_field_jobs = getNgoIn_the_field_Jobs($ngo_id);

if(!empty($in_the_field_jobs)) { ?>
   <h5>Work in the Field</h5>
<?php } ?>
```

So I want that Work in The Field shows only if it returns data, but it doesn't work... It shows even if it returns 0.

Comment: What is $db?  You probably want to return the query results from your function, not the result of the `query` method call, which likely returns some sort of DB connection object.  If this is a PDO object, you need to use `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` subsequent to the query itself.

Comment: I find the use of ( ' ) a bit confusing here.

Comment: Is your code contains mysql_fetch_array or mysql_​fetch_​assoc ?

Comment: You should show us your database class. We can't see what exactly `query` does. Like @EatPeanutButter says. For all we know, it's just preparing your query and doesn't return any result at all. Just the object.

Comment: @sukalogika We no longer live in the stone age. Stop using deprecated code.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with :

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

my $db was a PDO Connexion ($db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find this easier to read - but see about bound queries...

```
"
SELECT j.*
     , ngo.title ngo_title
     , ngo.money ngo_money
     , ngo.time ngo_time
     , ngo.love ngo_love
     , ngo.rating ngo_rating
     , ngo.logo ngo_logo 
  FROM in_the_field_jobs j
  JOIN ngo 
    ON ngo.ngo_id = j.ngo_id
 WHERE j.ngo_id = $ngo_id;
"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you are using looks like JSON but it doesn't check out as valid. See [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)... Editing it to make it valid (single line)...

```
{"room": [{"single_room": 1, "twin_room": 3}], "total_amount": [{"amount": 20899}], "travelernum": [{"total": 1 }]}
```

OR (Multi-Line)...

```
{
    "room": [{
        "single_room": 1,
        "twin_room": 3
    }],
    "total_amount": [{
        "amount": 20899
    }],
    "travelernum": [{
        "total": 1
    }]
}
```

If this is the format all your strings are in, you can manipulate them into valid JSON by first by using...

```
$original_string = '{"room":[{"single_room":1,"twin_room":3}]}{"total_amount":[{"amount":20899}]}{"travelernum":[{"total":1}]}';
$new_string = str_replace("}{", ",", $original_string);  // replace }{ with ,
```

Once your string is in valid JSON format, converting to a PHP array because rather simple, use something like this...

```
$BookingDetail = json_decode($new_string, true);  //true param gets assoc array
```

I tested all the code above and it works.See PHP json_decode() function reference for more detail on converting JSON strings to PHP Arrays.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the called query function.
When I see this code, it's hard to say. Can be a custom DB-Class or any other library. If it is something else than PDO it would be important to know which lib is used here.

If it is a PDO Query, then it only returns FALSE if the statement does not work --> on mysql Error. If it's empty it returns the PDO-Statement object, which is not "empty". It simply has no data.

http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php:

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

```
// built statement
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT `in_the_field_jobs`.*, `ngo`.`title` AS `ngo_title`, `ngo`.`money` AS `ngo_money`, `ngo`.`time` AS `ngo_time`, `ngo`.`love` AS `ngo_love`, `ngo`.`rating` AS `ngo_rating`, `ngo`.`logo` AS `ngo_logo` 
                FROM `in_the_field_jobs` 
                INNER JOIN `ngo` 
                ON (`ngo`.`ngo_id` = `in_the_field_jobs`.`ngo_id`)
                WHERE `in_the_field_jobs`.`ngo_id` = ' . (int)$ngo_id );
// return the array
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

should do the trick.